# what is the difference between ovs and ovsk?

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, openvswitch

when running mininet topology, we can use ovs or ovsk for --switch argument in mininet's **mn** command, for instance:

```
mn --custom topo.py  --topo topo --mac --switch ovs --controller remote
mn --custom topo.py  --topo topo --mac --switch ovsk --controller remote
```

So I wonder if there is any difference between these two commands?

As openvswitch can run on user space or kernel space, I thought it might be related to that, ovsk means ovs kernel space. However I couldn't find any information about this on documentations and google.

Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the mn code in [mn git](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/bin/mn):
ovsk and ovs point to the same class of object OVSSwitch, "ovsk" is still existing  for compatibility reason, but actually they are the same.

```
SWITCHDEF = 'default'
SWITCHES = { 'user': UserSwitch,
         'ovs': OVSSwitch,
         'ovsbr' : OVSBridge,
         # Keep ovsk for compatibility with 2.0
         'ovsk': OVSSwitch,
         'ivs': IVSSwitch,
         'lxbr': LinuxBridge,
         'default': OVSSwitch }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can verify [Giuseppe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9858192/giuseppe) answer from Mininet's python code as well where inside the **node.py** file on **line 1253**, `OVSKernelSwitch = OVSSwitch` is written.